# How to create a local token list variable in LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3, token-lists, scoping

The `\tl_new:(Nc)` functions create a new token list variable globally. Is there a way to create a new token list variable locally?

Comment: I think the idea is that you define a variable (defined globally), and then `set` it locally. You can reuse that one locally everytime you want. What's the problem with that? Why would you need to define locally? By the way, you always have `\l_tmpa_tl` and `\l_tmpb_tl` available. Otherwise, you can actually `\tl_set:Nn \local { .. }` wherever you want (unless there's some check activated).

Comment: @Manuel: When you use local variables, you do not have to worry that they will be changed by another function. You also reduce the risk of name clashes.

Comment: @EvanAad Doesn't work in TeX due to the way scoping occurs, which is basically why we didn't go with local variable _creation_.

Comment: When you `set` locally a globally defined variable you can be sure that the definition inside that group is the one you gave it.

Comment: Use `\tex_def:D`

Comment: @HenriMenke `:D`on't hehe

Comment: @EvanAad If you have a macro that itself defines `\local`, then calling it in a scope where you “locally declare” `\local` will change the value notwithstanding. There is no “local variable” like in other programming languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Yes and no'. If you are sticking to the official programming approach then 'no', as the method that the team have decided on is that all variables should be *declared* globally. On the other hand, if you decide to 'roll your own' then you can do

```
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \l_my_tl { }
```

as ultimately a token list is a macro with no arguments (at least in the current implementation). Unlike variables, there is no checking on pre-existence with `\cs_set_nopar:Npn` or similar. Note that I am *not* encouraging this, but you can do it. (There are a few places internally where we need to do this, most obviously in defining the `tl` operations themselves!)

(Note that `\tl_set:Nn \foo` with an undeclared `\foo` will create it locally *unless* checking is active. One of the checks that is available is to pick up exactly this non-supported behaviour.)

The reason for this approach is that experience suggests that this is the best way to deal with variables in TeX. Variables in TeX are scoped by groups (primitives `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`, `{`/`}`, _etc.), not by placement in (macro) definition. The team experimented with local creation of variables, not just `tl` but also other types. That is technically achievable but does not fit particularly well with TeX's underlying scoping: it could be read as suggesting that

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \foo:
  {
    \<var>_local_new:N \l_my_<var>
    % Code
  }
```

is local to the definition rather than to a group. When it became clear that this approach was not particularly helpful, the local initialisation was dropped leading to the current position, that all variables should be globally declared even if assigned locally.

(Register-based variables are more 'scarce' than those using macros, so there is very little need to worry about `tl` or similar: the 'savings' offered by local *creation* of variables apply most to for example `int` or `dim` types. Note that also register-based variable names do have to be declared, whilst one doesn't have to for macro-based ones. However, one aim the team have is that people using `expl3` shouldn't rely on implementation details: we reserve the right to alter how variables are created internally provided the API stays the same.)

Comment: May be explain that one could implement `tl` with `toks`? May be that way it's more understantable (given that one actually could think of implementing `tl` with `toks`, that I might be wrong).

Comment: @Manuel If we'd gone with a `toks`-based approach from day one then yes, but the API for `tl` does say they can be used without an accessor. As such, we can't change to a register-based 'back end'. (I have done experiments with `expl3`-like code that uses `toks` exclusively, particularly as LuaTeX offers various manipulation primitives.)