# How to dynamically define l3keys

Tags: latex3

In learning how to properly distinguish between the different function signatures in LaTeX3 (and other features), I want to try a more complex example of dynamically generating l3keys, since it requires dynamically defining several different things in different contexts.

I have the following MWE that tries to dynamically generate keys:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\definekey{mm}{
  \tl_new_local:N \l_examplea_mod_tl
  \tl_new_local:N \l_examplea_key_tl

  \tl_set:Nn \l_examplea_mod_tl {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_examplea_key_tl {#2}

  \keys_define:nn { \l_examplea_mod_tl }
  {
    \l_examplea_key_tl .tl_set:N = \l_ \l_examplea_mod_tl _ \l_examplea_key_tl _tl
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{m}
  {
    \keys_set:nn { examplea } { #1 }
    \typeout{\l_examplea_foo_tl}
    \typeout{\l_examplea_baz_tl}
    \prop_put:NnV \l_examplea_main_prop {foo} \l_examplea_foo_tl
    \prop_put:NnV \l_examplea_main_prop {baz} \l_examplea_baz_tl
  }

\prop_new:N \l_examplea_main_prop

\definekey{examplea}{foo}
\definekey{examplea}{baz}

\examplea{foo=bar,baz=asdf}

\prop_show:N \l_examplea_main_prop

\end{document}
```

The goal is essentially this. Define a new key like this:

```
\definekey{mymodule}{mykeya}
\definekey{mymodule}{mykeyb}
```

which should become:

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  mykeya .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_mykeya_tl
}
\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  mykeyb .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_mykeyb_tl
}
```

which effectively becomes:

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule } {
  mykeya .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_mykeya_tl
  mykeyb .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_mykeyb_tl
}
```

I am not close to getting this to work I don't think, probably making a few mistakes. The error I'm getting is this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\definekey #1#2->\tl_new_local:N
                                 \l_examplea_mod_tl \tl_new_local:N \l_examp...
l.34 \definekey{examplea}{foo}
```

The goal is to dynamically define keys in `\keys_define:nn`.

Comment: What makes you think that `\tl_new_local:N` exists?

Comment: @egreg Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14405/latex3-how-to-define-a-variable-locally/14412 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393631/how-to-create-a-local-token-list-variable-in-latex3 (the latter covers why we didn't take this path).

Comment: In any case, if  you actually read the error you can see that it says `Undefined control sequence`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the argument placeholders and `.tl_set:c` for building the token list name.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\definekey{mm}
 {
  \keys_define:nn { #1 }
   {
    #2 .tl_set:c = { l_#1_#2_tl },
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{m}
  {
    \keys_set:nn { examplea } { #1 }
    \typeout{\l_examplea_foo_tl}
    \typeout{\l_examplea_baz_tl}
    \prop_put:NnV \l_examplea_main_prop {foo} \l_examplea_foo_tl
    \prop_put:NnV \l_examplea_main_prop {baz} \l_examplea_baz_tl
  }

\prop_new:N \l_examplea_main_prop

\definekey{examplea}{foo}
\definekey{examplea}{baz}

\examplea{foo=bar,baz=asdf}

\prop_show:N \l_examplea_main_prop

\end{document}
```